# Why generalized vectors can be written locally as sum of vectors and 1-forms?

Tags: complex-geometry, fiber-bundles, fibration

I would like to understand better this point.

In generalized complex geometry the generalized bundle $E$ is defined as a non-trivial fibration of the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ over the tangent bundle $TM$, where the fibration is given by a gerbe.

1) Is this fibration different from the concept of non-trivial fibre bundle? (I don't know anything about gerbes - I just know something about fibre bundles). I mean, can I write locally $E$ as $TM \times T^*M$? Is it because of this fact that sections of $E$ can be written locally as elements in $TM \oplus T^*M$?

2) About sections. By definition, I would expect a section of (the fibre bundle) $E$ to be a map $s: TM \rightarrow E$ satisfying $\pi \circ s = id_{TM}$. In particular, $s(v)$, with $v \in TM$, should be an element of the fibre $T_v^*M$, right?
How does this match the answer to the previous question? (In other words, how does a generalized vector locally written as $X = v + \xi$, with $v,\xi$ in $TM,T^*M$ respectively, act on $w \in TM$? )

Comment: This $E$ is a vector bundle $E\to M$ and it fits to an exact sequence of vector bundles $0\to T^*M\to E\to TM\to 0$ over $M$. As a vector bundle it is isomorphic (globally, but not naturally) to $TM\oplus T^*M$. By a section people mean a section of $E\to M$. However, $E$ is not just a vector bundle, it has an additional structure (Courant bracket or somesuch), and this extra structure does depend on the gerbe (via its class in $H^3(M,\mathbb R$).

Comment: Sry, I keep not understanding why sections can be written locally as elements in $TM \oplus T^*M$. Can you be more explicit? Thank you for your time!

Comment: sections of $E$ can be written even globally as sections of $TM\oplus T^*M$, just because $E\cong TM\oplus T^*M$ as a vector bundle. That "locally" thing comes, I guess, from the additional structure on $E$, which is locally simple but globally a bit more complicated.

Comment: I am confused. If it is a bundle, it should be locally $TM \times T^*M$, right? Then, why/how do you see/have the intuition that $E \cong TM \oplus T^*M $?

Comment: I am confused about your confusion :)  Maybe one thing - I perhaps should have written $(T\oplus T^*)M$ in place of $TM\oplus T^*M$ - it's not $TM\times T^*M$

Comment: If $E$ is the bundle with fiber $T^*$ over the base $T$, locally it is $T \times T^*$. We should agree in this point.
I want to understand why instead $E$ is isomorphic to $T \oplus T^*$